# Is it bad to hide content for SEO?

Tags: seo, google, googlebot, content, blackhat

I'm designing a mobile CSS file for my website. It normally has a top navigation bar, like in here, Stack Exchange's sites. In my mobile version, I plan to hide the topbar, and put a button, which toggles the topbar on/off, but default it is off.

Will Google ever find about my site's mobile version? The URL is the same. And if it does, will it consider this as a "black-hatting"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it will not be black hat as you have placed a button to turn it on and off. Imagine if its a black hat then there are millions who are using buttons to hide content using button like "see more".

Answer (score 3):

That's absolutely safe. The Googlebot only gets upset when you "cloak" content on your page. That is, if you detect the Googlebot user agent and serve up a modified/different page to manipulate the bot.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the case then why do a lot of mobile sites running on WordPress have a mobile on/off switch, they would be penalised by Google but they are not, so it seems for the moment to be safe to do.